# Can we have a tag for "nurturing"?

Tags: feature-request, tags

As per the subject line - it's (very) applicable to my question [here](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/67673/animals-who-lay-eggs-and-dont-play-any-further-role) (and, I'm sure, many others), but isn't available!

Answer (score 2):

A tag can be made by any user with [300 rep or more](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags) in case of graduated sites like Bio. To make a new tag just type it in and hit 'Enter'. In your case, you do not have enough rep here on Bio (you do on the [Database Administrators stack](https://dba.stackexchange.com/), for that matter). Newly made tags remain devoid of a description (tag info) so it's appreciated if a user feels that a new tag is justified to provide a tag description (an excerpt and where possible a full tag description).

Now on to your specific question - would I, personally, support a new 'nurture' tag? No, I do not. We have the [development](https://biology.stackexchange.com/tags/development/info) and [reproduction](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reproduction) tags and I think the reproduction tag suffices for your [linked question](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/67673/name-for-a-set-collection-of-eggs-which-are-laid-and-receive-no-nurturing-of-any). Honestly, I do not see much benefit in another additional tag here. For a new tag to be useful a reasonable amount of questions need to exist or expected to be asked in the future. Given the (low) amount of questions being asked involving the nurturing of offspring in specific, I would vote against creating this tag.

Comment: It would most likely be another abondoned tag.

Comment: @Chris - exactly. We do have the occasional mammalian-related questions on mammary glands and milk production, but they are quite scarce imo.